# How to get current time in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: updatelistitems, date

It seems everytime I use "today" I get the current date but always at 12:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I always use **Modified** field (Of course in the case WF changes anythings - even the status update is enough).